# Django rest framework filter numbers less than list

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using DRF and package Django-Filter version 1.1.

In get call I am passing more than one values like 10,20,30, 40 in query parameter as below,

http://websiteapi.comp/searchFilter?persona=name&age=10,20,30

so based on the value sent in **age** parameter, in this case 10,20,30, I want get all the records which are **less than** 10,20,30 values.

Below is the my code snippet

```
class ListFilter(Filter):
  def filter(self, qs, value):
    value_list = value.split(u',')
    return super(ListFilter, self).filter(qs, Lookup(value_list, 'in'))

class SqureFeetFilter(Filter):
    def filter(self, qs, value):
        value_list = value.split(u',')
        return super(SqureFeetFilter, self).filter(qs, Lookup(value_list, 'range'))

class ProfileFiltter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    person = ListFilter(name='person')
    sf = SqureFeetFilter(name='age',lookup_expr='range')

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields =  [ 'person','age']

class ProfileSearchVieset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
        queryset = Profile.objects.all()
        serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
        permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
        filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
        filter_class =ProfileFiltter
```

Current by using range look_up expression I am able to get value between two number, but when there are more than 2 values, not able to get less than value between passed number.

**example**: if I pass **?age=10,20,30**, then result can be like this 10,12,13,17,19,10,23,22,25,29,30.

Please guide me

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Django Filter uses Django Field Lookups to perform filtering.

The field lookup `range` translates to an SQL `BETWEEN` clause and can only take 2 values to perform a range (a lower and an upper). You can't pass more than 2 values to a BETWEEN clause.

To be able to filter on more than 2 values, you need to apply the same filter twice with different values. Like Filter(1,6) and Filter(9,12)

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#range

Comment: I want apply filter on more than one value, at the same time result should be less than or equal to value, not exact passed value. example: if I pass 10,20,30, then result can be like this 10,12,13,17,19,10,23,22,25,29,30.